# How to define the line style in advance of plot function

Tags: plotting

I have a set of three plots and I want to define the line style for these plots, but I do not want to define this inside the plot function, but outside the plot function, like assigning to a variable. how to do this?

```
 style1 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}]}
style2 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{8, 20}]}
style3 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
   AbsoluteDashing[{4, 18, 40}]}
p1 = Plot[Sin[π*x], {x, 0, 1}, style1];
p2 = Plot[Sin[2 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, style2];
p3 = Plot[Sin[3 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, style3];
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap `style1`,`style2` and `style3` with `Evaluate`:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style1];
p2 = Plot[Sin[2 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style2];
p3 = Plot[Sin[3 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate@style3];

Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, force evaluation by passing `style1`,`style2` and `style3` as arguments:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[π*x], {x, 0, 1}, #]& @ style1;
p2 = Plot[Sin[2 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, #]& @ style2;
p3 = Plot[Sin[3 π*x], {x, 0, 1}, #]& @ style3;
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

You can also inject the styles using `With`:

```
p1 = With[{style1=style1},Plot[Sin[π*x], {x, 0, 1},style1]];
p2 =  With[{style2=style2},Plot[Sin[2 π*x], {x, 0, 1},style2]];
p3 = With[{style3=style3}, Plot[Sin[3 π*x], {x, 0, 1},style3]];
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way of general style definition in MMA 12 is:

```
st=Sequence["color","thickness", "any-of-other-style-definitions"];
Plot[f[x],{x,x0,xl},st, PlotRange->All]
```

The `Sequence` produces the true sequence of definitions which are not wrapped by any additional figure brackets {  }. Thus, one can use it with any following options like `PlotRange` or something else without `Evaluate`.

Comment: tried `style1 = Sequence[
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}]}];
p1 = Plot[Sin[\[Pi]*x], {x, 0, 1}, style1]`?

Comment: @kglr, it is strange. As I know, the `Sequence` is specially created for such purposes..